# How to run and see output after Visual Studio Solution file (.sln) has been built?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, itk

I am new to Visual Studio and CMake. I am trying to configure Insight Toolkit (ITK) in my laptop. I have done the following steps:

> 1. Downloaded the ITK Source Code from the ITK repository.
> 2. Configured and Generated Build files using CMake (Version 3.23.2)
> 3. Built Visual Studio Solution files (Visual Studio 2019)

Now I want to run a *Hello World* code in C++ to check everything is configured correctly. For this, I have done the following:

> 1. Created a folder named *HelloWorld* which contains two files

> > a. HelloWorld.cxx
> > b. CMakeLists.txt

> 2. Created another folder named *HelloWorld_build*, which contains CMake configuration files (executed from command prompt), and project build files (executed in Visual Studio).

Everything has run smoothly up to this point . The *HelloWorld_build* folder contains the *HelloWorld.sln* file. However, I am still not able to see the output. What is the step to see the output?

Comment: Press F5 for start debugging

Comment: Did that. Got an error message saying "Unable to start program. C:\..\..\x64\Debug\ALL_BUILD. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: That either means your build failed, or your build is misconfigured in some way.

Comment: Ok. Can you suggest some means by which I can find out the error? I did not receive any error message anywhere in the process.

Comment: *"Unable to start program. C:\..\..\x64\Debug\ALL_BUILD"* Just means you've selected the default target (`ALL_BUILD`) as startup target; this isn't an executable target but just a target that when built results in the equivalent of `make all` of a makefile project. Just select your executable target from the solution explorer, open the context menu and click "Set as Startup Project". This should change the target to bold and allow you to run it via the debugger mentioned by Markus Mayer. You can specify the initial startup project in the cmake files btw.

Comment: Note that I still expect issues with dlls of this ITK not being available via usual search for dlls at runtime...

Comment: "Just select your executable target from the solution explorer" How to do this? Please mention the steps.

Comment: I could run it finally following fabian's instructions!! Thank you so much for all your help.